I'm trying to use the pandas read_html() function to scrape data but need to pass in a username and password
I'm somewhat new to programming. The basic idea is that I'm working on a project and need to send a request to a website and scrape some data from it. However, the website I'm trying to retrieve data from requires a subscription (in the form of a username and password) to access it.
Sending a request without the details does not work.
import pandas as pd
import requests
import yfinance as yf

url = 'https://learn.mystrategicforecast.com/courses/take/insidethenumbers/multimedia/13520859-insidethenumbers-today'
auth = {
    'j_username': *my_username_or_email* ,
    'j_password': *my_password*
}

df = pd.read_html(url, storage_options=auth)
df

I tried calling the read_html() function directly without any additional parameters. The error I got was a 403 Error:
HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
So I think this is because I need to somehow pass in a username/email and password, which I didn't do before.
I figured out how to do this with just a request (I used requesst.get), and it said that the request was successfully sent (the status code is 200).
However, there are still two problems I'm facing:

The first is that when I try to print r.content (r is the request itself), it prints a lot of what seems to be code rather than the webpage content itself.
I need to be able to get a successful request through read_html() rather than requests.get().

I tried passing in a dictionary with a username and password and got something with requests.get(), which was the very long string of code on one line. However, I still got the Error 403 with read_html().
Sorry for the long post, but can anyone please help in this?

maybe you have to use requests to get data. And if server uses JavaScript to generate content on page then it may need to use Selenium to control real web browser which can run JavaScript.

maybe load page in browser and save it in file to see what server can send to you. If it uses <div> and css to format table then read_html can be useless because it can find data only in <table>. In browser you may also use shortkey Ctr+U to see source HTML. Or you can open DevTools (shortkey F12 or Ctrl+Shift+C in Firefox) to see HTML generated by JavaScript

If you get status 200, how looks the result?

@furas do I need to use any of the methods from selenium or is installing it enough?

@furas when save the file in downloads, it looks mostly the same and when i inspect the html page, the data is already stored in a table (I saw ). however, when I use ctrl + u, I cannot see  anywhere in the code

@Hermann12 is just a very long string (one line) with a lot of \n. Even when I try to print it, it does not properly process the \n and just prints it in one line. It looks more like code though.

if you don't see <table> when you use Ctrl+U then it uses JavaScript to generate table. But requests and pandas can't run JavaScript - so they can't get data. You may need Selenium to control real web browser which can run JavaScript. OR you may check tab Network in DevTools to see if javascript reads table from server as HTML or as JSON - and then you could use reqeusts to get it from this url (of course it will need to run first requests with login and password to login, and it will need to use requests.Sessison).

@furas I might go with the Selenium option. Do I just call the Selenium.get() method instead or is there a different method that I would need to use to access the table with js?

selenium need to create object webdriver.Chrome() or webdriver.Firefox() to control browser Chrome or Firefox and later you have to search data in HTML using xpath or beautifulsoup - so it needs more code than only Selenium.get()
